# how do you extract data from json using beautifulsoup in django

Tags: json, beautifulsoup, django-views

Good day. I'm facing an issue while trying to extract values from json.
First of all my beautifulsoup works very fine in the shell, but not in django. and also what I'm trying to achieve is extracting data from the received json, but with no success. Here's the class in my view doing it:

```
class FetchWeather(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'forecastApp/pages/weather.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        url = 'http://weather.news24.com/sa/cape-town'
        city = 'cape town'
        url_request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request.content, 'html.parser')
        city_list = soup.find(id="ctl00_WeatherContentHolder_ddlCity")
        print(soup.head)
        city_as_on_website = city_list.find(text=re.compile(city, re.I)).parent
        cityId = city_as_on_website['value']
        json_url = "http://weather.news24.com/ajaxpro/TwentyFour.Weather.Web.Ajax,App_Code.ashx"

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
            'Host': 'weather.news24.com',
            'Origin': 'http://weather.news24.com',
            'Referer': url,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36',
            'X-AjaxPro-Method': 'GetCurrentOne'}

        payload = {
            "cityId": cityId
        }
        request_post = requests.post(json_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        print(request_post.content)
        context['Observations'] = request_post.content
        return context
```

In the json, there's a array "Observations" from which I'm trying to get the city name, the temperature high and low.

but when I tried to do this:

```
cityDict = json.loads(str(html))
```

I'm receiving an error. Here's the traceback to it:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 4067 (char 4066)
```

any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You don't define a variable `html` in the code that you've shown us. Where is that?

Comment: Good day and thanks for the answer. This line cityDict = json.loads(str(html)) of code was done in shell, as I was attempting to access it. If successful then I can put it in the django. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. and the link to the expected json is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621105/json-data-format-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your JSON data inside `request_post.content`:

- there are JS date object values there, for instance:

  ```
  "Date":new Date(Date.UTC(2016,1,26,22,0,0,0))
  ```
- there are unwanted characters at the end: `;/*"`.

Let's clean the JSON data so that it can be loaded with `json`:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = request_post.text

def convert_date(match):
    return '"' + datetime(*map(int, match.groups())).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + '"'

data = re.sub(r"new Date\(Date\.UTC\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)\)",
              convert_date,
              data)

data = data.strip(";/*")
data = json.loads(data)

context['Observations'] = data
```

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk sure, added an import statement.

Comment: thanks figure out about the datetime: from django.utils.timezone import datetime.